# Get third biggest value in multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an input array containing n entries representing hours. (until 24). For each hour, there is an array containing people (bob and alice) with a value. I would like to get the third biggest hour of each people in ouput. (See output example).

Is there an easy way to to that in PHP ?

```
$input = array(
    '0' => array(
        'bob' => 8
        'alice' => 19
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'bob' => 2
        'alice' => 1
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'bob' => 9
        'alice' => 0
    ),
    'n' => array(
        'bob' => 6
        'alice' => 7
    ),
    ...
);
```

I would like to get this output:

```
$output = array(
    'bob' => 6,
    'alice' => 1,
);
```

Comment: Did you try to write something?

Comment: "Is there an easy way to to that in PHP ?"   Yes, there is. Many ways. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, not limited to bob and alice only, handles the case of many names.

```
$results = [];

foreach($input as $array)
    foreach($array as $name => $hours)
        $results[$name][] = $hours;

$results = array_map(function($v){
    natsort($v);
    $v = array_values($v);
    return $v[count($v) - 3];
}, $results);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 3):

```
$bobs = array_column($input, 'bob');
$alices = array_column($input, 'alice');
rsort($bobs);
rsort($alices);
$result = ['bob' => $bobs[2], 'alice' => $alices[2]];
```

**[SEE WORKING DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/19n5)**

Comment: Thanks for this working demo. Could you please provide an update considering that the name of entry bob and alice are dynamic. We don't know in advance the name of these column. We have to extract the third biggest value for each name : in example bob, alice but it could be jack, paul, henry...